# How to get the list of installed library packages only?

Tags: command-line

I want to get the list of installed library packages only from terminal.

Is there any command for that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
/sbin/ldconfig -p
```

The -v option will show the libraries version.

Result:

```
267 libs found in cache `/etc/ld.so.cache'
        libz.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libz.so.1
        libz.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/libz.so
        libxslt.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libxslt.so.1
        libxml2.so.2 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2
        libxcb.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1
        libxcb-xlib.so.0 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libxcb-xlib.so.0
        libwrap.so.0 (libc6) => /lib/libwrap.so.0
        libvolume_id.so.0 (libc6) => /lib/libvolume_id.so.0
        libuuid.so.1 (libc6) => /lib/libuuid.so.1
        libutil.so.1 (libc6, hwcap: 0x8008000000008000, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.8) => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libutil.so.1
        libutil.so.1 (libc6, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.8) => /lib/libutil.so.1
        libutil.so (libc6, OS ABI: Linux 2.6.8) => /usr/lib/libutil.so
        libusb-0.1.so.4 (libc6) => /lib/libusb-0.1.so.4
        libusb-0.1.so.4 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libusb-0.1.so.4
        libulockmgr.so.1 (libc6) => /lib/libulockmgr.so.1
        libt1x.so.5 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libt1x.so.5
        libt1.so.5 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libt1.so.5
        libtiff.so.4 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libtiff.so.4
        libticw.so.5 (libc6) => /lib/libticw.so.5
```

If you want to turn that list into a list of *packages*, you can do something like this:

```
dpkg -S $(/sbin/ldconfig -p | awk 'NR>1 { print $NF }')
```

And you can further massage that to cut out errors, unneeded components and duplicates:

```
$ dpkg -S $(/sbin/ldconfig -p | awk 'NR>1 { print $NF }') 2>/dev/null | sed 's/\: .*$//' | sort -u
akregator
ark
binutils
calligra-libs
comerr-dev
compiz-core
dolphin
e2fslibs:amd64
freeglut3:amd64
gettext
...
```

Comment: Something wrong with this command, it doesn't show anything. $ dpkg -S $(/sbin/ldconfig -p | awk 'NR>1 { print $NF }') 2>/dev/null | sed 's/\: .*$//' | sort -u

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there's a guaranteed way to know from a package name that a package is a "library" (if that's even a solid definition in itself) but you can find installed packages that start and end with `lib` fairly easily:

```
dpkg -l | awk '($1 == "ii") && ($2 ~ /^lib|lib$/) { print $2 }'
```

Some packages contain "lib" that aren't libraries. You'll probably need to exclude `librarian` and `libreoffice` from those:

```
dpkg -l | awk '($1 == "ii") && ($2 ~ /^lib|lib$/) && ($2 !~ /^(libreoffice|librarian)/) { print $2 }'
```

This is still going to miss out a dearth of `python-...` libraries.

Answer (score 1):

And aptitude came to the rescue:

```
aptitude search '?and(?section(libs), ~i)'
```

It reads: looks for packages that contains `libs` in their `?section` and that are installed (`~i`).

You can use this to look for just all libraries in your repository:

```
aptitude search '?section(libs)'
```

This method obviously need of aptitude.

Comment: Note, this will work if the packages comply with Debian policies. If a library isn't in the library section, then it will not be included, even if it's a library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command for finding all installed packages in Ubuntu:

```
apt list --installed
```

You can search for a specific package using:

```
apt list --installed <package_name>
```

In case the above commands are not be permitted to be run by the user, then add `sudo` in front of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
pkg-config --list-all
pkg-config --list-all | grep <package>
```

Comment: pkg-config is a computer program that defines and supports a unified interface for querying installed libraries for the purpose of compiling software that depends on them. It will not give you a complete list of installed packages.